# babel-preset-es2015 not destructuring objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to get the following ES6 code to transpile using Babel 6:

```
let { id, name, type } = this.props;
```

but when I run the presumably transpiled code, Chrome Dev Tools gives me a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" error.

In my `package.json` I have:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
  "bower": "^1.6.5",
  "gulp": "^3.9.0",
  "gulp-babel": "^6.1.0",
  "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0"
}
```

and in my `gulpfile.js` I have

```
gulp.task('babel', () => {
  return gulp.src('public/js/src/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(babel({
      presets: ['react', 'es2015']
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/build'));
});
```

Does anybody have some ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Try `{"presets": ["es2015", "react"]}`

Comment: Can't repro this on my end. Your exact setup worked fine for me. Are you sure you're including the *build* file in the browser and not the *src* flle?

Comment: I made a dummy project to test this and I can't reproduce it either... `let { id, name, type } = this.props` is being converted to `var` statements in my test project, just not in my actual project. Getting the same non-results by calling from the command line `babel --presets=es2015 --presets=react public/js/src --watch --out-dir public/js/build`.